# Issue with starting a function with generated variable every certain time

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, function, queue

I do generate 'top_gainer_keys' every 5 minutes from the function 'top_3gainer_keys' based on market, each time (5 minutes) I get new 3 keys, I want the function 'system_start()' to work on the new generated keys each time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OCv8.png)

I have tried many methods but I did not get it as I am looking for, the best thing I got that I succeeded with generating top 3 gainer keys then the system start processing them BUT when after 5 minutes I get new 3 keys the system never change processing the first list of keys.

Comment: Please do not post images of code -- post the code itself into the question (after the code has been pasted into the question, select all the lines and then enter `Ctrl-k` to format it correctly).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.